# Use "vanilla" assert in Rspec?

Tags: ruby, rspec

How can someone use vanilla `assert` in Rspec?

```
require 'rspec'

describe MyTest do
  it 'tests that number 1 equals 1' do
    assert 1 == 1
  end
end
```

The error I get:

```
undefined method `assert' for
#<RSpec::ExampleGroups::Metadata::LoadFile:0x00000002b232a0>
```

Notice that I don't want to use `assert_equal`, `eq`, `should`, or other mumbo jumbo.

Comment: Why do you need this? Also, I think that `assert` is from [`Unit tests`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/test/unit/rdoc/Test/Unit/Assertions.html), and not from `RSpec`.

Comment: @Wikiti because `assert` feels much more elegant than the other stuff IMO

Comment: Why aren't you just using minitest then, if you don't want Rspec features? https://github.com/seattlerb/minitest#specs

Comment: @sevenseacat because at my workplace most people use Rspec

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this pretty easily:

```
require 'rspec/core'
require 'test/unit'

describe 'MyTest' do
  include Test::Unit::Assertions
  it 'tests that number 1 equals 1' do
    assert 1 == 2
  end
end
```

(if you want to be able to run the tests by doing `ruby foo.rb` then you'll need to require `rspec/autorun` too). This pulls in all of those assertions. If you really don't want any extra assertions, just define your own `assert` method that raises an exception when the test should fail.

Conversely you can easily use rspec's expectation syntax outside of rspec by requiring `rspec/expectations` - rspec3 is designed to be modular.

Comment: Thanks! Saved me some headache.

Answer (score 0):

### Configure RSpec to use MiniTest

```rb
RSpec.configure do |rspec|
  rspec.expect_with :stdlib
end
```

Then you can use [all the asserts](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-3.0.2/libdoc/minitest/rdoc/Minitest/Assertions.html) offered by MiniTest from the standard library.

### ...or Wrong

Alternatively, you can use [Wrong](https://github.com/sconover/wrong) if you like asserts with a block:

```rb
require 'wrong'

RSpec.configure do |rspec|
  rspec.expect_with Wrong
end
```

```rb
describe Set do
  specify "adding using the << operator" do
    set = Set.new
    set << 3 << 4
    assert { set.include?(3) }
  end
```

Inspired by this [blog article on RSpec.info](https://rspec.info/blog/2012/07/mixing-and-matching-parts-of-rspec/).